# How games with infinite world deal with finite variables

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

When I was missing around with Unity once, I encountered a problem where the main player's position start losing precision, wobbling and 
movement smoothness turns into jitter.

It turns out I was going too far off the origin point which is too much for unity's vector3 floating point to handle.

In graphic. You can easily overcome this issue by just looping through a certain range. Ignoring that will result in an issue similar to this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: https://youtu.be/wGhBjMcY2YQ

Which makes me really wounder, how do developers over come finite variables to create infinite worlds. I personally haven't dipped my toes in making infinite world but I have encountered the graphic floating point error.

If developers relay on the fact that players will never reach the point where that error start to occur then technically, it's not an infinite world.

I would love to hear from the experts.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's probably a better fit for the [Game Dev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Primarily by not creating things that are actually infinite